# How to redirect to external link after payment in android app?

Tags: android, redirect

I have created my own android app and now I'm stuck, how can I redirect to user to external link after completion of payment in android app?

I have used `AIDL` in-app billing so can any one post sample code here which I can replace with my external link?

I am newbie in coding. So I haven't tried anything much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

You can read more in :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

You can create a method:

```
public void newActivity(String uri){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

to call the method:

```
newActivity("https://www.google.com");
newActivity("https://www.youtube.com");
newActivity("https://www.iosdroid.es");
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now i have 3 in-app products and i have 3 extrenal urls for each product. Now issue is my coder has made code which making me confused where to create intent or where I can put this intent code for 3 different exttenal urls?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [developers page about this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api) you can find:

> c. When the checkout flow finishes (that is, the user successfully purchases the item or cancels the purchase), Google Play sends a response Intent to your onActivityResult method. The result code of **the onActivityResult has a result code that indicates whether the purchase was successful or canceled**.

So, getting this intent in the activity is the first step:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int 
requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, 
resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       //redirect to the new page
    }
}
```

Redirecting to the new page is easy:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";//here goes your url
Intent i = new 
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i); //this starts it in the browser
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@rajithaperera_81165/integrating-google-play-in-app-billing-into-an-android-application-d86678571413) you have a great complete tutorial!

If you have multiple products and different urls for each product, you can check which product has been bought, in activityresult, 
with the data bundle.

Comment: Where to check which product bought? In androidmainfest file or in homefragment details where i have saved all details